# Double loop, double voltage source circuit analysis problem, with three unknown voltages/currents, using Kirchhoff's laws and Ohm's law

Tags: voltage, circuit-analysis, current, kirchhoffs-laws, ohms-law

I'm currently studying the textbook *Fundamentals of Electric Circuits*, 7th edition, by Charles Alexander and Matthew Sadiku. Chapter **2.4 Kirchhoff's Laws** has the following practice problem:

> Find the currents and voltages in the circuit shown in Fig. 2.28.
> [image]
> **Answer:** \$v_1 = 6 \ \text{V}\$, \$v_2 = 4 \ \text{V}\$, \$v_3 = 10 \ \text{V}\$, \$i_1 = 3 \ \text{A}\$, \$i_2 = 500 \ \text{mA}\$, \$i_3 = 2.5 \ \text{A}\$

It seems to me that we have two loops here. For the first loop, we have \$-10 \ \text{V} + 2i_1 + 8i_2 = 0\$. For the second loop, we have \$4i_3 - 6 \ \text{V} - 8i_2 = 0\$, where I have \$8i_2\$ by Ohm's law instead of \$-8i_2\$, because the current \$i_2\$ is actually going from + to - for the \$8 \ \Omega\$ resistor (and despite this being counter to the clockwise direction of the loop, my understanding is that this results in a positive current for the purpose of the Ohm's law calculation). Finally, if we designate the top middle node, then we have that \$i_1 - i_2 - i_3 = 0\$. Is my reasoning here correct?

Comment: Your first loop formula is incorrect. It should be: 10 volts  = 2I1 + 8I2

Comment: @Andyaka Oops, you're right; that was a typo. Thanks!

Comment: `Is my reasoning here correct?` - it wasn't correct but you've fixed the formula. However, I'm unsure what else there is to answer. Personally, I don't think your `reasoning` is now wrong but it's not how I would write it at all.